# running rails migrations on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, postgresql-9.3

I have deployed a rails app on VPS with passenger and nginx. Now I have added a migration like following:

```
def change
    add_column :order_products, :order_id, :integer
    add_index :order_products, :order_id


    Order.find_each do |order|
      OrderProduct.where(order_number: order.order_number).find_each do |op|
        op.update_attributes!(order_id: order.id)
      end
    end
end
```

I executed `rake db:migrate` command on VPS but this doesn't add any column to OrderProduct table.

`db/schema.rb` contains the following:

```
create_table "order_products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "order_number"
    t.string   "item_code"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "order_id"
  end

  add_index "order_products", ["order_id"], name: "index_order_products_on_order_id", using: :btree
```

where there is `order_id` column is included. Also, in `schema_migrations` table I don't see the latest migration version added.

Do I need to do anything else to make it work on production?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell rake that you want to run the task in `production` environment because per default it would run the migration against the `development` database:

On older versions of Ruby on Rails (`< 5`)

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

On newer versions of Ruby on Rails (`>= 5`)

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

As @spickermann said try using `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` if that does not work try

```
rails generate migration AlterOrderProduct 

def up
    add_column(:order_products, :order_id, :integer)
    add_index (:order_products, :order_id)
    Order.find_each do |order|
      OrderProduct.where(order_number: order.order_number).find_each do |op|
        op.update_attributes!(order_id: order.id)
      end
    end
end

def down
    remove_column(:order_products, :order_id, :integer)
    remove_index (:order_products, :order_id)
end
```